# Retain hover over effect on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 links which act as a bit of a navigation bar, they are a light blue to start with, when one of them is hovered over or clicked I would like them to change color and retain that color until another link is selected.

I have had a good search for a solution and there are many but they all seem to be for a particular case and I just can't seem to adapt them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

heres my html here, I have a css file making it look pretty as well.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>


  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>

  $(function() {

    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({

      event: "mouseover"

    });

  });


  </script>

<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Menu bar</title>
<style type="text/css" />
</style>

  <link href="navPanelStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

 <div id="tabs">

  <div id="topBar">
  <ul>

    <li><a href="#Booking">BOOKINGS</a></li>

    <li><a href="#Rooms">ROOMS</a></li>

    <li><a href="#news">NEWS</a></li>

    <li><a href="#Specials">SPECIALS</a></li>

    <li><a href="#About_us">ABOUT US</a></li>

  </ul>
  </div>
<div id="content_Wrapper">
  <div id="Booking">

<p>Bookings</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Rooms">

<p>Rooms</p>
  </div>

  <div id="news">


<p>news</p>
  </div>


  <div id="Specials">

<p>Specials</p>

  </div>



  <div id="About_us">

<p>About us</p>

  </div>


</div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you really need to post all this HTML to illustrate the point? Please keep the examples small and relevant.

Comment: You can't do this with pure CSS, you need JavaScript

Comment: @whiteElephant Is this JS solution that you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use Jquery to do this you can try this way, to retain a style for selected tab.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kU9NY/)

#### JS

```
$("#tabs").tabs({

    event: "mouseover",
    select: function (event, ui) {

        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(ui.tab).addClass('active'); // ui.tab in the select event will be currently selected tab.

        // Do stuff here
    }

});
```

#### Css

```
#tabs .active {
    color:Blue;
}
```

if you want to apply over the entire tabe you can apply your styles to `li` tab element as follows:-

`$(ui.tab).closest('li').addClass('active');`

#### [Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/TsSw3/)

Comment: @whiteElephant Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hey PSL your demo is what I am looking for. Having trouble implementing it my self though. Am i missing something with the script above. The script above should open each tab right? and then control the hover over effect. I have just put it in a <script> tag ...   <script>

 
$("#tabs").tabs({

    event: "mouseover",
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(ui.tab).closest('li').addClass('active')
        // Do stuff here
    }

});
  </script>
I then added the #tabs.active part to my css file. Is this what I should be doing ?

Comment: Yes that should make it work. Can you check if you have any errors in the console also just put a conolse.log inside select call back function to see if it goes there, if both happens then inspect the selected tab to see if the tab's `active` styles have been applied or not..

Comment: The tabs no longer work, and I am getting the error "SyntaxError: missing } after function body", If I add in a } then I get "SyntaxError: missing } after property list". How do I check if the tabs active styles have been applied? Thanks for your help. ...

Comment: I have rid my self of the error, but still no tab effect or roll over effect.

Comment: Can you just paste your js code snippet in the fiddle and paste in in the comment.

Comment: ANything in the console, did you check if it is going inside the function?

Comment: here is my fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/njlnick/p2D3s/, the tabs work here but not the hover effect. Must be something in my css or something in the program I am using (expression web) I copied the html from fiddle and it doesn't work when I save it through expression.. Whats going on ?

Comment: Got the issue your css. There should be space between #tabs and .active as it is applied on the child not on #tabs `#tabs .active {
    color:Blue;
    background-color:navy;
}`

Comment: Still nothing, is this working for you? Appreciate the help dude.

Comment: I am here to help!!! :) Check my new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MWSYC/, does it work...? copy the scripts as is including the script tag... and see...

Comment: Okay it still wasn't working but I noticed down the left side you had a Jquery UI 1.9.2 extension which I didnt have. I gave it this and its working. Thank you so much for your help, you are a legend. Really appreciate how this community are so willing to help others. How can I ensure my website has this Jquery ui 1.9.2?

Comment: You are welcome... I don't think you need latest jquery ui for tab to work. But just see the specs for tab.. You may need a later version, you can download it from Jquery website. Also if this helped resolved please mark it as answer... :)

Comment: Lol no longer working on my computer, do I need to download JQuery for it to work or is it enough to have it like this  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a piece of hover-over listener JavaScript code that removes *active* class from the element that was last activated and add it to the one that's hovered over.

Like the following:

```
$(".menuitem").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass("active_menuitem");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active_menuitem");
    }
)
```

A *menuitem* can be anything that the CSS related to the *active* menu item class can be applied to